# Cooper-Zare-Theory - Photoionization simulated in Python

Tags: atomic-physics, computational-physics, software, ionization-energy, laser-interaction

My concrete problem is that I want to calculate cross-sections for photoionization transitions in argon in Python. For example from the excited state 3S^23p^56d into the continuum.

For this, I found Cooper-Zare theory in several sources, including "Introduction to Photoelectron Angular Distributions". The formula for the cross section is, according to the above-mentioned book(p.87):
(i am doing some reverse engineering here)

$$
\sigma_{pd} = \frac{16\pi^2}{3(2l_0 + 1)} [l_0\Re^2_{l_0-1}+(l_0 + 1)\Re^2_{l_0+1}]
$$
where $l_0$ is the initial azimuthal quantum number (in the upper case: $l_0=2$, because of the d-state) and
$$
\Re_{l_0\pm1} = \int_0^{\infty} r^3R_{nl_0}(r) G_{k,l_0\pm1}(r) \, dr 
$$
where $n$ is the principal quantum number (here $n=6$). And
$$
G_{kl}(r) = \frac{e^{i\delta_l} \sin(kr - l\pi/2)+ e^{-i(kr + l\pi/2)} e^{-2i\delta_l}\sin(\delta_l)}{kr}
$$
which originates from
$$
| f \rangle \propto 4\pi\sum_{l, m} i^l e^{-i\delta_l} Y_{lm}^* (\hat{k})Y_{lm}(\hat{r}) G_{kl}(r)
$$
where $\hat{k}$ defines a unit vector in the direction of the photo-electron momentum vector. And this comes from:
$$
| f \rangle \propto  \sum_{l=0}^{\infty} (2l + 1)i^l e^{-i\delta_l} P_l(\cos\theta_s) \left[\frac{e^{i\delta_l} \sin(kr - l\pi/2) \left(\frac{1}{2} + e^{-i kr + l\pi/2}\right) e^{-2i\delta_l} \sin(\delta_l)}{kr}\right]
$$

which is assumed to be the final state for the dipole approximation
$$
\frac{d\sigma_{pd}}{d\Omega} = |\langle f |O| i \rangle|^2
$$
with the operator for linearly polarized light:
$$
O = r^4 \sqrt{\frac{4\pi}{3}} Y_{1 0}(\mathbf{r})
$$

**My problem is that I don't know where to get the phase shifts $\delta_l$ of the partial wave, which are used in the formula for $G$.**

I would be very grateful for any tips.

```
import scipy.special as spe
import scipy.integrate as integrate

#radial wave function
def psi_R(r,n=1,l=0):
    rr=r
    coeff = np.sqrt((2.0/n)**3 * spe.factorial(n-l-1) /(2.0*n*spe.factorial(n+l)))
    laguerre = spe.assoc_laguerre(2.0*rr/n,n-l-1,2*l+1)
    return coeff * np.exp(-rr/n) * (2.0*rr/n)**l * laguerre

### the radial portion of the final-state wave function divided by kr
def G_kl (r,k,l,d_l):
    gg=(np.exp(1j*d_l)*np.sin(k*r-l*np.pi/2)+np.exp(-1j*(k*r+l*np.pi/2))*np.exp(-2j*d_l)*np.sin(d_l))/(k*r)
    return gg

### e radial dipole integral
def R_l0(n,l0,l,k,d_l):
    integ= integrate.quad(lambda r: np.real(r**3*psi_R(r,n,l0)*G_kl(r,k,l,d_l)), 0, np.inf,limit=100000, epsabs=np.inf)
    return integ[0]

### asymmetry parameter β
def beta(n,l,k,dl_p1,dl_m1):
    R_p1=R_l0(n,l,l+1,k,dl_p1)
    if l-1>=0:
        R_m1=R_l0(n,l,l-1,k,dl_m1)
    else:
        R_m1=0
    chi= l*(l-1)*R_m1**2+(l+1)*(l+2)*R_p1**2-6*l*(l+1)*R_m1*R_p1*np.cos(dl_p1-dl_m1)
    epsi=(2*l+1)*(l*R_m1**2+(l+1)*R_p1**2)

    return chi/epsi

def cross_sec(n,l0,k,dl_p1,dl_m1):
    r_lp1=R_l0(n,l0,l0+1,k,dl_p1)
    r_lm1=R_l0(n,l0,l0-1,k,dl_m1)
    return 16*np.pi**2/(3*(2*l0+1))*(l0*r_lm1**2+(l0+1)*r_lp1**2)
```

Comment: I think you might consider also asking in the matter modeling community: https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You don't actually have any formulas written down. Or equations. You have a bunch of out-of-context Python functions. Could you perhaps explain what it is you are *supposed* to be modeling? And why you think you cannot use scipy's integration routines?

Comment: @AvishaiBarnoy please don't push away content that is perfectly on-topic here to another site needlessly. You should at least indicate to OP that matter modeling could be viable if no answers are obtained here.

Comment: Thanks @KyleKanos! You are right. I added the formulas and tried to introduce them via reverse engineering. I just want to know the "probability" of ionization from the above-mentioned state via a laser pulse which has 1.27 eV -> 0.88eV above the ionization threshold)

Answer (score 0):

I can make a detailed answer later but I have solved similar problems using [Scattering Theory: The Quantum Theory of Nonrelativistic Collisions](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0486450139) and  [Physics of Atomic Nuclei](https://www.wiley.com/en-us/Physics+of+Atomic+Nuclei-p-9783527413508) chapter 4 and 14. You will also need some considerations about the density of states in the final expression for the cross section.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Unfortunately, I only have access to the first source "Scattering Theory". There I did not find the phase delay in the mentioned chapter in the final state. Which lines do you mean there exactly? I would be very grateful for the more detailed answer.